# Разработка для Unity3d без Unity3d

Tags: visual-studio, unity3d

Кто-нибудь пробовал подобный режим разработки?- частично разработку игры веду на работе, но юнити там ставить нельзя (портативно юнька не работает), поэтому логику пишу Visual Studio. Однако, хоть и пишется на C#, но все таки "C#"-приложение и "Unity3d"-приложение это довольно разные вещи. Есть ли какие-то фитчи в помощь, чтобы кодить в VS, но с учетом требований Unity3d?

Comment: А что мешает настроить `Radmin` или `teamviewer` или другие программы для удаленного доступа к рабочему столу и не парить мозг?

Comment: Вам достаточно через Unity3d открыть проект в VS, если ассет соответствующий есть. В дальнейшем можете работать только в VS.

Comment: @Suvitruf Автор написал что нельзя юнити на работе ставить. Поэтому и подключиться не к чему будет. Хотя, конечно, если автор имел в виду установку с целью разработки, а не вообще, то тогда можно так сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у себя дома один раз в Unity3d сделает синхронизацию с VS, зальёт в git. На работе запулит всё из гита и откроет в студи, Unity3d уже не нужен будет.

Comment: @Suvitruf  Не знал. Хотя и логично) Думал Юнити в любом случае должна быть в системе. Тогда напишите об этом в ответе. Чуть пошире)

Comment: Алексей Шиманский "А что мешает настроить Radmin или teamviewer или другие программы для удаленного доступа к рабочему столу и не парить мозг" - это проблематично на данный момент. Хотя проторчав всю жизнь на usb-интернете как-то даже забыл о таком подходе.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, для кодинга сам Unity3d не нужен. Вам нужно лишь 1 раз синхронизировать юнити и Visual Studio. Для этого нужно поставить visual studio tools

1. Читаем [доку](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html) и ставим visual studio tools.
2. Заходим в Unity3d и открываем проект в студии, проект синхронизируется с VS и создаст необходимые файлы.
3. Теперь вы можете открывать проект в студии без использования Unity3d. Можете запушить проект в git.
4. На работе запулите проект из гита.
5. Можете открывать его в студии, Unity3d уже не нужен.

Comment: На сколько я помню если unity на компьютере нет, то из проекта он не может UnityEngine.dll, UnityEditor.dll найти, и тогда разрабатывать нормально не получится. А Visual Studio с последними версиями автоматически устанавливается)

Answer (score 3):

Скопируйте себе UnityEngine.dll, UnityEditor.dll, они находятся где то в папке где установлен Unity. Таким образом все возможности кода в Unity буду доступны.
Сделайте ссылки на эти dll-ки в вашем проекте.
Должно работать, точно сказать не могу как себя поведёт.
Так же можно включить удалённый рабочий стол.